# Analyzing Recursive Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I've often been slightly stumped by recursive algorithms that seem to require magical leaps (with a large dose of shrunken notation born of an ink shortage) of logic.

I realize that the alternative is to simply memorize the Big O notation for all the common algorithms but at a certain point, that approach fails. For example, I am happy to disclose the performance for bubble sort, insertion sort, binary tree insertion/removal, mergesort, and quicksort but don't ask me to come up with the performance of AVL trees or Djikstra's shortest path algorithm off the top of my head.

Where can I go to get:

1. A discussion of recursive algorithm analysis that uses words instead of a profusion of symbols
2. Practice problems to confirm that my newly-obtained understanding is actually correct

Example:

Bad:

Sigma v e T (1+cv)

Possible 'good' equivalent:

The amount of work required for 1 node in the tree (which is 1+the # of children of a node), which is then executed once for every element in the tree where the original node is the root.

Side commentary:

I could simply watch a video for every single algorithm because there's no way to make one's voice turn into a subscript (or any of the other contortions) but I suspect that would take an inordinate amount of time compared to reading textual descriptions.

Update:

Here's 1 source of solved problems: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/ (this tackles #2 above)

Comment: You should learn to get comfortable with the communication of these ideas in symbols. It's efficient, precise, and the language that almost everyone uses.

Comment: @Jason: If you are cs student or mathematical and theoratical focused. For a good programmer it should be enough to understand the meaning.

Comment: +1 to Jason's point. For getting comfortable (and better than most people, actually!) with notation and analysis, I recommend the wonderful book *[Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics).* Just the first two chapter should be enough (plus possibly the last), but it's so well written it's hard to resist reading the other chapters as well.

Comment: I should comment that I was dramatically underselling myself in the original post. :D
I'm quite handy with things like sigmas, aleph-nulls, and so on. I just have trouble with the way the material is presented in the textbok that was required by my introductory class when I was getting my B.S (hence my commentary on ink shortages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'officially' answer this question...

Source of sample problems: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/

An explanation of analysis for CS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

TopCoders has a great source of tutorials and thorough explanations. Have you tried them out?

http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index&module=Static

Comment: Well, their particular tutorials on recursion ([Part 1](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=recursionPt1), [Part 2](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=recursionPt2)), while very good, do not go into much detail of analysis.

Comment: I've reviewed the tutorials and must agree that there is almost nothing on analysis.